# Xamarin CommunityToolkit - Video record rotated

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to record a video from Xamarin CommunityToolkit.

When the app it's in portraid mode video it's saved like it's in landscape mode and it's rotated at 90.

I have seen that many people using images can rotate them 90 degrees by controlling the orientation of the phone. But how can I do this with videos?

This is Camera XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MYAPP.Views.CameraPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-MYAPP.ViewModels"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MYAPP.Views;assembly=CustomView"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">

            <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            
            <xct:CameraView
                Grid.Column="0"
                x:Name="cameraView"
                CaptureMode="Photo"
                FlashMode="Off"                  
                MediaCaptured="CameraView_MediaCaptured"
                OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
   
        </StackLayout>

        
        <Button
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            WidthRequest="500"    
            HeightRequest="70"
            CornerRadius="15"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,AutoSize,AutoSize"
            Margin="0, 0, 0, 30"
            x:Name="doCameraThings"
            Clicked="DoCameraThings_Clicked"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Text="Registra" />
        
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is CameraContentPage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using MYAPP.Services;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Core;

namespace MYAPP.Views
{
    public partial class CameraPage : ContentPage
    {

        public CameraPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            Title = "Camera";
            cameraView.CaptureMode = CameraCaptureMode.Video;
            cameraView.VideoStabilization = true; 
        }

        void DoCameraThings_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            cameraView.Shutter();
            doCameraThings.Text = cameraView.CaptureMode == CameraCaptureMode.Video
                ? "Stop Recording"
                : "Snap Picture";
        }

        void CameraView_OnAvailable(object sender, bool e)
        {
            doCameraThings.IsEnabled = e;
        }

        void CameraView_MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            switch (cameraView.CaptureMode)
            {
                default:
                case CameraCaptureMode.Default:
                case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
                    
                    break;
                case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
                    FileMediaSource file = e.Video.File;

                    DependencyService.Get<IStorage>().exportFileMediaSource(file, "asd.mp4");

            
                    doCameraThings.Text = "Registra";

                    DependencyService.Get<IToast>().ShortAlert("Video salvato");

                    break;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using  Xamarin.CommunityToolkit ver 1.2.0. How can rotate video when saved ?

MediaCapturedEventArgs Rotarion property it's readonly and return 0.
API Level 29

Comment: What version of the Toolkit are you using? I think I saw a pull request for this... Also what platform are you trying to do this one?

Comment: I think that the `MediaCapturedEventArgs e` has a `Rotation` property,It's readonly. But at least you can get how much you have to rotate it

Comment: Xamarin.CommunityToolkit ver 1.20. MediaCapturedEventArgs  Rotarion property it's readonly and return 0.

Comment: I'm using API Level 29

Comment: There is no method in XamarinCommunityToolkit which can rotate videos, you can search how to do it in native platform(ios/android) and use dependency service to achieve them.

Comment: How are you exporting the video through messaging centre?